# Как проводить операции со значениями в Tkinter введенными в поле и выводить их при нажатии кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Хочу сделать програмку в Tkinter чтобы одни значения, а потом путем расчета выводить результат
Не получается, выдает ошибки

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def click_button():
    value = aple.get()  # получаем значение
    aple.set(value * 1.7)  #Считает вес семян в граммах с 1 кг яблок


# Создание окна.
root = Tk()
root.title("Яблочный калькулятор")
root.geometry("300x300")

aple = StringVar(value = 0)    # значение по умолчанию


label2 = ttk.Label(text = "Введите вес яблок")
label2.pack(anchor=W, padx=10)

entry = ttk.Entry()
entry.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)


btn = ttk.Button(text="Пересчитать", command=click_button)
btn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)

label3 = ttk.Label(textvariable=aple)
label3.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)


# Запуск приложения.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Какие именно ошибки выдает? Не забыли значение из StringVar в целое число преобразовать, случайно?

Comment: У меня проблема, значение пытаюсь умножить на 1.7 и результат не виден, какой должен быть, даже float применил в функции.

Answer (score 0):

Вы получаете значение яблока, которое по умолчанию равно 0.

```
value = aple.get()  # получаем значение
```

А вам нужно получить значение с поля entry

```
value = int(entry.get())  # получаем значение
```

так же следует конвертировать его в int, так как мы получаем string.

P.S. еще советую вписать корректное имя переменной (с aple на apple)

```
aple = StringVar(value = 0)    # значение по умолчанию
```